# User login with php/javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php script that I call through ajax to initialize session variables for a user login.  When I retrieve the session info later on it doesn't seem to be there.  What is missing from this.  I must say I am assuming that the $_SESSION variable is there.  I haven't done this before.

PHP code that searches for user in db and initializes session variable

```
while (true) {
    $md5_pw = md5($password_text);
    $r_getuser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (user_name = BINARY '".mysql_real_escape_string($l_un_em)."' OR email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($l_un_em)."') AND (password = '$md5_pw' OR temp_password = '$md5_pw') AND status >= 0");
    if (mysql_num_rows($r_getuser) == 0) {
        /* echo $messages['log_un_em_pw_incorrect'];
        return; */
        $return['return_code'] = -1;
        $return['return_msg'] = $messages['log_un_em_pw_incorrect'];
        echo json_encode($return);
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_getuser);
    /* if ($row['privs'] < 1) { echo $messages['log_no_privs']; break; } */
    if ($row['temp_password'] == $md5_pw) { //new password
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password = '".$md5_pw."', temp_password = NULL WHERE user_id = '{$row['user_id']}'");
    }
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    if ($row['login_0'][0] == '9') { //first login
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET login_0 = '".$today."', login_1 = '".$today."', login_cnt = 1 WHERE user_id = '{$row['user_id']}'");
    } else {
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET login_1 = '".$today."', login_cnt = login_cnt+1 WHERE user_id = '{$row['user_id']}'");
    }
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['unm'] = stripslashes($row['user_name']);
    $_SESSION['uml'] = stripslashes($row['email']);
    $_SESSION['cL'] = $row['language'];
    /* echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=livemass_CENTER34.php">'; */ //default page
    break;
}
```

PHP code to retrieve session variable.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo 'user id '.$_SESSION['uid'].'<br/>';
echo 'username '.$_SESSION['unm'].'<br/>';
echo 'uml '.$_SESSION['uml'].'<br/>';
echo 'cL '.$_SESSION['cL'].'<br/>';

?>
```

Javascript to show session info.

```
$.ajax({
      url: "get_session_info.php",
      type: "GET",
      data: {},
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      success: function (response) {
      alert ('session info response <br/>'+response);
      },
});
```

Comment: I see no `session_start();` anywhere?

Comment: please post entire php code instead of snippets.. are you sure u added a session_start()? It should be added on every page u plan to use $_SESSION

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysql). If you care to learn, [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a quite good PDO-related tutorial.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate question; please take a look at: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787292/why-cant-i-access-session-variables-from-my-ajax-called-php-script

Comment: @tereško  If PDO is a sane and sound language and an improvement over MySQL I am willing to learn!  Quick question... MySQL allowed you to select the database separate from the connection, i.e. you connect with `mysql_connect` then you select a db with 
`mysql_select_db`.  Is there a similar way in PDO.

Comment: @user823527, no , that is not a part of API. I am not sure how it works "under the hood", but the normal workflow would be to create two separate instances. The point here is that you usually would be injection the connection in the object which uses it, and when you need to test that object ,you can replace the connection with at a fake ( usually known as "mock" ).

Comment: I cannot recommend PDO enough. Prepared statements in MySQL means that you outline the actions to be performed, and the user input can only be values (not executing functions). Essentially this means that even if a user sends "' OR WHERE 1=1', the "OR WHERE" will be taken as a value and not an execution (and in turn probably return 0 results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `session_start()` to all your files which access `session` varibale values

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// remaining items

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Great.  That was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

To build on what @Frits said. To use php sessions you must place the function `session_start();` at the beginning of every page that you want to access `$_SESSION` on.