# Why is the SESSION variable not accessible in the AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using an AJAX call in my script to fetch some data from my php script.
The AJAX call properly executes, I've tested that so far. But unfortunately, the SESSION variable doesn't seem to be available.

I'm currently refactoring some code and this AJAX call goes to some code which before was inside the same file as the scriptcode. There, the respective php code still executes and the SESSION variable definitely is available there, otherwise the whole page would break (probably).

So I wonder whether I forgot to include something in my php file or something of this sort?

EDIT: I'll try to give minimal example of what code is behind the described behavior.

Code in Calling.php (yeah its javascript, but the author (not me) once decided to make a php file which contains both HTML, javascript and php...):

```js
<?php session_start(); ?>
<script>
//Lots of Code
function Caller(){
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:'called.php',
success: function(data){
//debugging function taking data;
},
error: function(xhr, statusText, err){
//debugging function taking xhr.status
}
}

)
}
//Lots of Code
</script>
```

Code in called.php

```
<?php
$test = $_SESSION["loggedUser"];

echo $test;
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Please post your code if so :) Thanks!

Comment: impossible to answer with the information provided.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787292/why-cant-i-access-session-variables-from-my-ajax-called-php-script
Isn't it duplicate?

Comment: what do you mean by tried?^^
I have some Try/catch in my php code if you mean that :D 
Otherwise, do you want my ajax Call or the PhP code? or Both?^^

Im programming on a Virtual machine so its difficult to copypaste, but I'll give you as much code as you want as long as I know what you want :D

Comment: @Skeptic123 — You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I access session variables from my AJAX-called PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787292/why-cant-i-access-session-variables-from-my-ajax-called-php-script)

Comment: did you run session_start() before you tried to access the session variable in called.php? It doesn't look like it. It runs in a separate context to calling.php so putting session_start() in calling.php has no effect on what happens in called.php.

Answer (score 3):

Ajax calls are not the same process as the original page being served, and require `session_start` being called again *for each request*.

You can do this safely (without an error or warning if it has already been called) like so:

```
if ( is_null($_SESSION) || !$_SESSION )
{
    session_start();
}
```

This should live in your bootstrap or index file, and should always be called/included/required from all requests to php, before any request-based logic runs.

Comment: The first paragraph is true, and is the core of the answer. The rest is outdated (`session_start` doesn't throw errors since 5.3.0), or opinion based (it's up to you where to put this, and having an single entry point in the form of an index file doesn't always apply).

Comment: As there is unfortunately a great deal of software still supporting severely deprecated php versions (cough WordPress), it is not appropriate to make assumptions about OPs use case that were not stated. As far as opinion, the context of the question is someone who does not understand the basics of `$_SESSION`, and for OPs need they are best served by not allowing the same issue to cascade elsewhere by taking care of it in one spot until they have sufficient innate expertise to understand when it does and does not apply.